# what's accomplished in vb.net by opening forms using frm.Show(Me)?

Tags: vb.net

I've inherited a VB.NET app that usually opens forms with frm.Show(Me).

What are the pros & cons of using the (Me) argument? When I remove it from the VB.NET code, I don't see any difference in the application's behavior.

Comment: That creates an *owned* window.  A very big deal.  An owned window is always on top of its owner and automatically minimizes when the owner is minimized.   Pretty visible in Visual Studio itself, all of its windows are owned windows.  Normally docked but you can drag them outside of their parent.  Next best thing to ShowDialog(), but without the crappy modal behavior.

Comment: Read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx)  The owner of the window is owned by the class that is showing the form, in other words `Me` .